# My laptop Wifi crashes a few minutes after boot

Tags: windows-10, laptop, internet-connection, control-panel

I have a 4 year old Razer Blade Stealth 12.5" (2016) and 5 days ago it started having this problem that would "fix" itself temporarily (in the beginning it worked for hours now for only a few minutes) by rebooting.

The problem: The Wi-Fi disconnects out of nowhere and even the option to toggle on/off in the toolbar disappears. Most Windows programs (Control panel, Search bar, Settings, Device manager, etc.) become very sluggish to the point of not working at all and freeze when I try to close them.

Every day since the problem started was worse then the day before, if I reboot my laptop now it only works normally for 2-10 minutes. After that I have to reboot again. Every other feature is working fine, apps like File explorer, PowerPoint and Google Chrome are not affected at all.

I tried to: Install/Update Razer firmware and Wi-Fi drivers. Performed a full virus check from windows Defender and Kaspersky. I uninstalled Killer Wireless. I reinstalled Windows. I checked for S.M.A.R.T errors on SSD. I checked for weird power options and a few other things.

Any help is appreciated,

Processor: Intel i5-7200U

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 620

network adapter: killer wireless-n/a/ac 1535 wireless

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Home 64 Bit

S.M.A.R.T with Samsung Magician

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eiuR.jpg

Comment: Have you done a disk check? Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: What is this? [edit] and add the output to the question.

Comment: I tried using HD Tune but could not make it see my ssds health, since its a samsung sdd I downloaded Samsung Magician and I pasted the info it gave me on the post. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please post a screenshot. That edit is useless as it is.

Comment: My bad, I'm new to this. I posted the screenshots